# How do I perform an auto-segue in Xcode 6 using Swift?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, segue

I wish to auto-segue from the main viewController to a second view controller after a set period of time after an app loads.

How do I do this?

Do I need to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If your UI is laid out in a Storyboard, you can set an `NSTimer` in `viewDidLoad` of your first `ViewController` and then call `performSegueWIthIdentifier` when the timer fires:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(interval: 8.0, target: self, selector: #selector(timeToMoveOn), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    @objc func timeToMoveOn() {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMainUI", sender: self)
    }
```

---

Here is how you set up the segue in the Storyboard:

1. Control drag from the File's Owner icon of the first `ViewController` to the second `ViewController`.
2. Choose "modal" from the pop-up.

[image: Seting up the segue]

---

1. Click on the *segue arrow* that appears between the view controllers.  In the *Attributes Inspector* for the segue...
2. Give your segue an Identifier.
3. Turn off *Animates* if you don't want to see the screen slide in.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this snippet of code:

```
let delay = 1 // Seconds
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.launchMainUI()
    return
}
```

which performs the `launchMainUI` method after `delay` seconds. Replace it with your own implementation, where you instantiate your view controller and present it, or simply invoke a segue.

Answer (score 0):

In your action you must write like this example

**self.performSegueWithIdentifier("name of segue", sender: self)**

after you must implemented this method

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{        
        if(segue.identifier == "name of segue")
        {
            var view : yourviewcontroller = segue.destinationViewController as yourviewcontroller
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4:

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 8.0, target: self, selector: #selector(segueToSignIn), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

@objc func segueToSignIn() {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignInSegue", sender: self)
}
```