# Transition to view through the timer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nstimer

I need to implement a smooth transition to another `View` using a timer.

For example, when I click on the start button and after 15 seconds pass, the automatic transition to another `View` takes place.

[image: Current Views]

Comment: Image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vmP9wrV9dUPvMKCvkARWWAvKT7wiU9iR

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26380148/1630618

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I perform an auto-segue in Xcode 6 using Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379462/how-do-i-perform-an-auto-segue-in-xcode-6-using-swift)

Comment: Welcome Dany, asking with code will be helpful for you because you can achieve in a different ways.

Answer (score 1):

In start button action start a timer with an incrementing counter variable. In the timer execution block if the count reaches 15, invalidate the timer and navigate to next view controller

```
@objc func startBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var count = 0
    let target = 15
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
        self?.label.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d", count/60,count%60)
        if count == target {
            timer.invalidate()
            self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "NextScreen", sender: self)
        } else {
            count += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just set the `timeInterval` to be 15 and not bother with the `count`? **EDIT:** I misread the question.

Comment: @NRitH In timer execution block count is used to update label.text. Check [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyzuW.png) in OP comment

Comment: Ah, you're right. I missed that.